# After getting data(as string) from URL/API, how to convert string type data to object type array in PHP

Tags: php, json

My data from 'file_get_contents(url)' is

```
$str = // example google.visualization.Query.setResponse(
{"x":"0.6","y":{"a":[{"id":"xyz","label":"xyz"},{"id":"xyz","label":"xyz"}],"b":[{"c":[{"id":"xyz","label":"xyz"},{"id":"xyz","label":"xyz"}]}]}});
```

i want to convert this string into object type array, i have already tried '**json_decode($str, true)**' and **html_entity_decode($str)** but did't succeed i have used **json_last_error()** also it return 4
i want output like this:

```
    // example google.visualization.Query.setResponse(
{
    "x":"0.6",
    "y":
        {
            "a":[
                {"id":"xyz","label":"xyz"},
                {"id":"xyz","label":"xyz"}
            ],
            "b":[
                    {"c":[
                        {"id":"xyz","label":"xyz"},
                        {"id":"xyz","label":"xyz"}
                    ]}
                ]
        }
});
```

after that i am using

```
$sValidJson = str_replace("// Data table response google.visualization.Query.setResponse(","",$str);
$sValidJson = str_replace(");","",$sValidJson);
$myArray = json_decode(json_encode($sValidJson), true);
```

now it doesn't generate error for json but still return its type as string not as json object

Comment: Provided data is __not__ a valid json.

Comment: yeah i know that's  json_last_error() return 4 what i can do to fetch from it because when using json beautifier online it return errors but still showing me as array, how they are doing ?

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Well you’d have to remove `);` from the end first, because that’s what makes it invalid.

Comment: i have remove it by str_replace and then i use json_decode(json_encode($str), true) but still it return its type as string not as json object

Comment: For php json is always a string (same as html). That's why you need decode to deserialize it into data structure. For pretty print you may use one of the options - [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)